# Moving multiple objects a fixed distance

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am currently making a game where I have several platforms flying around the screen. I have grouped all of them using the display.newGroup() and inserting them into that group. I would like to move these multiple platforms (which are all the same) a fixed distance at the same time. How would I do that?

I have tried using translation, but then, it seems that I can not move all of them a 'fixed' distance using it. Is there any other option?

Comment: Just post the code which you have tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use transition instead of translation, here s an example

```
 local group = display.newGroup()
 group.x = value
 group.y = value 

 -- (1) move square to bottom right corner; subtract half side-length

 transition.to( group , { time=1500, alpha=0, x=(w-50), y=(h-50), onComplete=listener1 } )
```

For more details,

https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/transition/to.html#examples